# Go mod download complaining about build constraints

Tags: kubernetes, go-modules, client-go

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is doing this. Another guy claims this works for him and that I have an environment issue. Yet every other dozen projects are working fine for me.

So just for the fun of it I started out with a *completely pristine* go environment. (rm -rf ~/go)

There is no go.mod/go.sum file. No other repos. No extraneous files or any kind laying around. Absolutely nothing in my go path other than my cloned repo.

I clone my repo and then with go modules enabled, "go get k8s.io/code-generator" and I get this error every time:

```
package k8s.io/code-generator: build constraints exclude all Go files in /Users/me/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/code-generator@v0.0.0-20190813220511-4e023f69fd57
```

So then I repeat the above test this time with a go.mod file specifying the k8s.io/code-generator version this requires (1.13.1). Same error.

Anyone have any idea what the deal is here? My suspicion is this is a macOS related issue or something.

Answer (score 3):

The one and only source file for the `k8s.io/code-generator` package has a [build constraint](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints) specifying [`+build tools`](https://github.com/kubernetes/code-generator/blob/6483f25b1faf70af19925981b3de8f01d6a53712/tools.go#L1).

The `go get` command “[resolves and adds dependencies to the current development module and then builds and installs them.](https://tip.golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Add_dependencies_to_current_module_and_install_them)”

Since the only source file for the package you have requested does not apply to your configuration (or, indeed, to most configurations), you should instead request that the `go` command stop after downloading the module, by passing the `-d` flag to the command:

```
$ GO111MODULE=on go1.13beta1 get k8s.io/code-generator
go: finding k8s.io/code-generator latest
can't load package: package k8s.io/code-generator: build constraints exclude all Go files in /tmp/tmp.qZqEJeHXeb/_gopath/pkg/mod/k8s.io/code-generator@v0.0.0-20190814140513-6483f25b1faf

$ GO111MODULE=on go1.13beta1 get -d k8s.io/code-generator
go: finding k8s.io/code-generator latest
```

With versions of the `go` command before `1.13`, you may need to also pass the `-m` flag to indicate that the path should be interpreted as a module rather than a package.

See also https://golang.org/issue/33526.

Comment: how could you achieve the same for go modules? there's no `-d` option

Comment: As of the time of writing, all currently-supported versions of the `go` command (1.13.8 and 1.14) accept the `-d` flag to `go get` in module mode.